# Glassfish JDBC Connection pool - specify specific schema name

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, web-applications, glassfish

I'm trying to set up a JDBC connection pool (WITH username and password)
However, the the schema name (which obviously wasn't set up by myself) was named something else and NOT the same as the username. Therefore, when my Glassfish web app runs, I got "unknown table or view" error.

I figure I can address this by hard-coding the schema on each and everyone of my entity classes, BUT I was wondering if there's a way to specify this in either in the JDBC connection pool or the JDBC resource that my application is using.

Comment: The schema name should be set in the connection pool definition, under URL property. Have you tried it? Post the connection pool definition

Comment: Can you specify if you are using Universal Connection Pool (UCP), a Java connection pool ?

Comment: @perissf Yes. I've tried adding the property under both the connection pool and the jdbc resources, but it doesn't work.
Googling around, I found out on Oracle site that such property does NOT exist on the JDBC connection pool

Comment: Which db are you using? Note that the properties are db-driven